# How to move object in corona sdk?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, coronasdk

Hey i am using this code to move (animate) my objects on the scene 
But it leaks the memory and stop responding.

```
//transition back
local function goBack( )
    transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 310, onComplete = startTransition})
    transition.to ( wall, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 200, onComplete = startTransition})
    transition.to (gate_a, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 255, onComplete = startTransition})
    transition.to ( stargate_a, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 255, onComplete = startTransition})
end

//transition start
function startTransition( )
    transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 310, onComplete = goBack})
    transition.to ( wall, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 200, onComplete = goBack})
    transition.to ( gate_a, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 255, onComplete = goBack})
    transition.to ( stargate_a, { time =10000, x = 700, y = 255, onComplete = goBack})
end

startTransition()
```

How do i move objects properly without leaking any memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do like this:

```
//transition back
local function goBack( )
    transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 310})
    transition.to ( wall, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 200})
    transition.to (gate_a, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 255})
    transition.to ( stargate_a, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 255, onComplete =   startTransition})
 end

 //transition start
 function startTransition( )
    transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 310})
    transition.to ( wall, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 200})
    transition.to ( gate_a, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 255})
    transition.to ( stargate_a, { time =10000, x = 700, y = 255, onComplete = goBack})
 end

startTransition()
```

Since all the time duration are same, no need to call onComlpete on all transitions.

---

And if you need, you can cancel the transitions inside the functions. For that, assign a name to the transition, check whether it is still in progres, then stop it. I'll show you an example. This is not mandatory, but if you still suffering from memory loss after implementing the above code, you can use it.:

```
local trans_1,trans_2;
local function goBack( )
    if(trans_1)then transition.cancel(trans_1) end   -- to cancel an existing transition
    trans_2 = transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 100, y = 310})
end

function startTransition( )
    if(trans_2)then transition.cancel(trans_2) end -- to cancel an existing transition
    trans_1 = transition.to ( wall2, { time = 10000, x = 700, y = 310})
end

startTransition( )
```

keep coding.............